# How to retry pytest selenium tests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, pytest

Use case:

1. run the selenium login test

- open website
- fill username and password field
- click login
- wait till main page is opened
- assert if main page is opened

2. if the login test failed -> retry (max attempt = 5)
3. collect retries
4. if the retries list is not empty - send status not ok. If list of failed tests is empty - send OK status

Problem:
the webdriver is not quite browser when the assertion faild, so when retry function is running again tests instead opening login page, main page is opened and test failed due to function is waiting for element to fill in (step: fill username and password field )

```
def retry_function(exception, max_attempt: int = 5, step: int = 2):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def result(*args, **kwargs):
            retry_count = 0
            while retry_count < max_attempt:
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except exception as err:
                    log.info(f"Retry test [{retry_count}/{max_attempt}]: \"{func.__name__}\" --> {err}. "
                             f"Sleep {step} sec before next retry")
                    time.sleep(step)
                    retry_count += 1

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return result

    return decorator
```

conftest.py

```
pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    output = yield
    report = output.get_result()

    if report.failed:
        node_id = report.nodeid
        pytest.failed_nodes.append(node_id)
 
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def driver(request):
    firefox_options = Options()

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(
            service=Service(Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()),
            options=firefox_options
        )

    failed_before = request.session.testsfailed

    yield driver

    if request.session.testsfailed != failed_before:
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        test_name = f'{request.node.name}_{now}'
        take_screenshot(driver, test_name)

    driver.close()
```

test_login.py

```
@retry_function(exception=AssertionError, max_attempt=1, step=1)
def test_login(self, driver):
   login_page.login
   assert is_login_page_opened()
```

and based on failure I would like to make an action:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def finalizer(request):

    def fin():
        if pytest.failed_nodes:
            resp = api.send_msg(f'Failed tests {pytest.failed_nodes}')
        elif not pytest.failed_nodes:
            resp = api.send_msg('OK')

    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check out [seleniumbase](https://seleniumbase.io/), it's a framework consisting of pytest and selenium. 
It has the function you need and to utilize it you just need to use the flags `--reruns=5` while running the tests.
It has many more functions which will make your life a lot easier, definitely worth checking out.